# I cannot find @ in my nodejs server

Tags: node.js

I post a email address to my nodejs server(I just learn it for a short time), but I find that the @ was replaced. How can I get my @ back? For example, I post

```html
1@1.com
```

but I get

```html
1%401.com
```

on my server.

Answer (score 1):

Pass it through `decodeURIComponent`

```
decodeURIComponent('1%401.com') // 1@1.com
```

By the looks of things your data is being URI encoded. `decodeURIComponent` decodes a URI encoded parameter

Comment: Thank you, I just test it and It helped me. I think maybe find and replace "%40" is just OK.

Comment: Glad to help, I recommend `decodeURIComponent` over a find/replace because then you don't have to worry about maintaining a map of replacements if you have issues with other characters. IMO if it's been URI encoded by the browser or the developer the best way to decode it is with a function that decodes URI encoded data and considering node has a function already no point reinventing the wheel :).

Comment: Yeah， I think it is complex to replace, and  will remember it.